# Is burning PVC with municipal waste 'acceptable' nowadays?

Tags: waste, plastic

I started to write a comment under the question [Is there an efficient way to dispose of credit cards?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-dispose-of-credit-cards) about the dangers of burning PVC, because this can lead to dangerous chlorine compounds in the smoke (notable: dioxine).
Upon searching for evidence for that I came across several links confirming this:

- [The dangers of PVC](http://www.pulpworksinc.com/dangers-of-pvc.html), at pulpworksinc.com, a maker of compostable plastic blister-pack replacement.
- [Polyvinyl chloride (PVC)](http://www.greenspec.co.uk/building-design/polyvinyl-chloride-pvc-environment-health/) from www.greenspec.co.uk, a firm involved in green building products and materials

... as well as links suggesting that this no longer is the case:

- [PVC incineration/dioxins](https://pvc.org/sustainability/pvc-recycling-in-europe/pvc-incineration-and-dioxins/) at pvc.org, i.e. The European Council of Vinyl Manufacturers
- [PVC: To Burn or Not to Burn?](https://waste-management-world.com/a/pvc-to-burn-or-not-to-burn) , at waste-management-world.com, the  International Solid Waste Management Association (ISWA).
- [7 Myths About PVC – Debunked](https://www.carlislesyntec.com/download.aspx?id=5534&fileID=6830), a (PDF) white paper from Carlisle SynTec Systems, a manufacturer of roofing materials

All these sources may not be objective.
**What is the current, state-of-the-art, objective knowledge that we have about burning municipal waste with PVC in waste incineration facilities?**

Notes:

- I'm not asking about [home burning](http://www.wecf.eu/cms/download/2004-2005/homeburning_plastics.pdf) or open fires; I'm asking about controlled burning in waste incineration facilities.
- The question is not about phthalates being used as plastic softeners during the lifetime of the product; only when incinerating.
- This is not just about credit cards, e.g. there's far more PVC landing in our waste because of blister packaging, and from pipes, vinyl flooring, hoses, cable coatings, medical devices, plumbing and automotive parts, upholstery, housewares, shower curtains, raincoats, toys, school supplies, food packaging, and shoes.
- The question could be extended to all halogenated plastics, i.e. made from chlorine or fluorine; not just PVC.

Comment: This article seems like a good place to start, but I was not able to find an open access version: [Catalytic conversion of waste plastics: focus on waste PVC](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jctb.1757)

Comment: The problem with burning PVC is that it produces hydrochloric acid; well , HCl ,which becomes acid when water is present as in a nasal passage.